# Confluent Control Center - Consumer is not listed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-control-center

I have the following code to connect to Kafka

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "myconfluentkafkabroker:9092");
props.put("group.id","test");
props.put("enable.auto.commit","true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","1000");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my_CG");
props.put("group.instance.id", "my_instance_CG_id");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put("key.deserializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"));
props.put("value.deserializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"));

KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("MyTopic"));
try {
    while (true) { 
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        {
            log.debug("topic = %s, partition = %d, offset = %d,"
                customer = %s, country = %s\n",
                record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(),
                record.key(), record.value());

            int updatedCount = 1;
            if (custCountryMap.countainsKey(record.value())) {
                updatedCount = custCountryMap.get(record.value()) + 1;
            }
            custCountryMap.put(record.value(), updatedCount)

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(custCountryMap);
            System.out.println(json.toString(4));
        }
    }
} finally {
    consumer.close();
}
```

Code didn't throw any errors but I still don't see the consumer listed

[image]

would this be an issue?

> props.put("group.instance.id", "my_instance_CG_id");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify the information that you see with the built-in tools that Kafka provides like `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`

You'll also need to actually poll messages and commit offsets, not just subscribe before you will see anything.

Otherwise, for that specific Control Center dashboard, it may require you to add the [Monitoring Interceptors](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/control-center/installation/clients.html) into your client

Comment: Yes, I do pull but it is printing 0 messages

Comment: Well, then use CLI tools to verify there is zero lag

Comment: how to print the ConsumerConfig values? something like 2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2021-03-31 19:14:32.367 INFO 38 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig : ConsumerConfig values:
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] allow.auto.create.topics = true
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] auto.offset.reset = latest
2021-04-01T00:44:32.367+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bootstrap.servers = [17xxx:9092]

Comment: Those should automatically get printed if you properly setup a SLF4J logger

Comment: any sample links? it is not printing for me

Comment: I usually use Logback, but Log4j2 would be better. This might help - https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-appenders-layouts-filters

Comment: so, all I need is the Log4j2 setup. nothing specific to kafkaconsumer itself, correct? would assume console appender work as well?

Comment: Correct. `kafka-clients` includes SLF4J. SLF4J requires an external logging library, such as log4j2 or logback

Comment: final question - props.put("group.instance.id", "my_instance_CG_id"); would this cause any issues? and prevent the consumer from reporting in the control center?

Comment: Not that I know of. Remove it. Does it change anything?

Comment: What happens when you specify two out of three brokers in the app? Would it cause any issues?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar Nope. The bootstrap protocol would return all of them, anyway